# write python dictionary to a file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm trying to split a csv file into multiple files, preserving the header each time:
So if my current original file is :

```
 <t> ID    Name   Position  <br> 1    Jose     Engineer <br> 2  Maria  Developer <br> 3 Keith  Manager</t>
```

I want to split it into 3 files :

`File1.txt`

```
<t> ID    Name   Position  <br> 1    Jose     Engineer <br>
```

`File2.txt`

```
<t> ID    Name   Position  <br> 2    Maria     Developer <br>
```

`File3.txt`

```
<t> ID    Name   Position  <br> 3    Keith     Manager <br>
```

I am able to build the key-pair dictionary, but if I use

```
json.dump(keys, file_ptr, ensure_ascii=False
```

I get unwanted `[` and `]` at the beginning and end of keys' list.

I also tried

```
writer = csv.writer(file_ptr)
writer.writerows(keys)
```

which splits each letter of the key like `N`, `a`, `m`, `e`, and so on.

Any suggestions?

Also, is it possible to avoid iterating over the keys in the dictionary  while printing the corresponding values?

Answer (score 1):

Change your csv code to use single row:

```
writer.writerow(keys)
```

or wrap the keys into a list:

```
writer.writerows([keys])
```

Comment: Yeah, using writer.writerow(keys) helps!
Thanks!
but the quote marks are gone, "John Baker" becomes simply John Baker

Comment: You don't need the quote marks unless the field contains commas.